# Not understanding whether to use notifyDataSetChanged() when elements in listview are updated?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have android application which uses listview with adapter of custom objects.

onCreate of activity if list of objects is available I populate adapter with previous objects and make a async call to fetch new objects and populate adapter.

While populating adapter again will old list of elements be removed and new will be added. I have not used notifyDataSetChanged().

```
private CustomAdapter listAdapter;
private GridView gridView;

            // this is onCreateView of fragment if i find old list in singleton i populate list and it shows on screen


            function onCreateView()
            {

            ...
            ...

            listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(),
                    CounterSingleton.getInstance(getActivity())
                            .getObjects());
            gridView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            ....
            ...
            new AsnycTask().execute();
            }


            class AsnycTask
            {

                // fetch new list and replace old list shown

                List<Objects> newList = fetchNewList();
                listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(
                                        getActivity(), newList);
                gridView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            }
```

Few questions here:

1. Do i need to use notifyDataSetChanged() in AsnycTask class after i populate adapter by creating new instance of it.
2. Will old list be removed and replaced by new list as per above code.

Comment: No need to use notifyDataSetChanged(),if you are creating new instance.....

Comment: and old list will be replaced by new one..

Comment: what do you actually want ? you want to remove old items with new ones or want to keep both ?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain remove old items and replace with new items in async class i have shown...

Answer (score 2):

> Do i need to use notifyDataSetChanged() in AsnycTask class after i
>   populate adapter by creating new instance of it.

No need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` because currently calling `setAdapter` method for ListView with new data-source

> Will old list be removed and replaced by new list as per above code.

Yes ListView will populate with new data.

**Note:**  Instead of calling `setAdapter` method again-2 for showing new data. create a method inside Adapter which will update current Adapter with new data.like:

```
public void addNewItems(List<Objects> itemList){

  1. clear data from current adapter
    for example if using ArrayList then

     ArrayList_Object.clearAll();
  2. Add itemList  in ArrayList_Object
     ArrayList_Object.addAll(itemList);

  3. Call this.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Now call `addNewItems` for update current apdater data from `AsnycTask` using same object which is created first time when ListView populated  :

```
listAdapter.addNewItems(newList)
```